Using KeyVaultSecurityKey as asymmetric signing key in OpenIddict server
I am trying to set up an OpenIddict server that uses Azure Key Vault keys to perform JWT signing (I am not trying to store an RSA key in an AKV Secret and then use that; I am trying to set up OpenIddict with credentials to use an AKV Key, for which it can request AKV to perform signing).
Below is a snippet of how one would create a JWT that uses such a key:
 var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    _configuration.Issuer,
    _configuration.Audience,
    claims,
    expires: expiration == null ? null : now.Add(expiration.Value),
    new SigningCredentials(
        new KeyVaultSecurityKey(
            _configuration.RsaKeyUri, 
            async (authority, resource, scope) =>
            {
                var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { resource + "/.default" }));
                return token.Token;
            }
            ), "RS256")
    {
        CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory() { CustomCryptoProvider = new KeyVaultCryptoProvider() }
    }
    );

From what I can tell from the available middleware in OpenIddict, it looks like the right approach is to use AddSigningCredentials
This is what I have tried to use thus far (paraphrased):
     services.AddOpenIddict() 
        .AddServer(options =>
        {              
            options.AddSigningCredentials(new SigningCredentials(
                new KeyVaultSecurityKey(
                    Configuration["JwtSigning:AkvKeyUri"],
                    async (authority, resource, scope) =>
                    {
                        var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                        var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(
                            new TokenRequestContext(new[] { resource + "/.default" }));
                        return token.Token;
                    }
                ), Configuration["JwtSigning:KeyType"]));

But on startup this complains that at least one asymmetric signing key must be configured. If using AddSigningCredentials does not achieve that, how am I actually supposed to do this?
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: At least one asymmetric signing key must be registered in the OpenIddict server options.
      Consider registering a certificate using 'services.AddOpenIddict().AddServer().AddSigningCertificate()' or 'services.AddOpenIddict().AddServer().AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate()' or call 'services.AddOpenIddict().AddServer().AddEphemeralSigningKey()' to use an ephemeral key.
         at OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerConfiguration.PostConfigure(String name, OpenIddictServerOptions options)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
         at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
         at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
         at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd[TArg](String name, Func`3 createOptions, TArg factoryArgument)
         at OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerFactory.CreateTransactionAsync()
         at OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)


Have you got the key successfully?

Seems like the OP posted a question on GitHub which has a pretty good explanation. Adding this for reference:
https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/2050

I think this is because the key hasn't been aquired successfully.
You could try replace the
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

to
var credential = new ClientSecretCredential("{tenantId}", "clientId", "{clientSecret}");

in order to make sure you have the correct credential the get the key.
Also confirm you have setup access policy for this client

